# How to import moment types definitions

Tags: typescript, momentjs, atom-editor

I have made an angular 1 project with typescript using this yeoman generator: https://github.com/FountainJS/generator-fountain-systemjs
It uses SystemJS and jspm to get dependencies but npm for type definitions (using DefinitelyTyped repository).

I have been struggling these last few days trying to import **moment** type definitions. 
I have installed moment using jspm, and i have discovered that it comes with its own type definitions, so if you call the command `npm install @types/moment --save-dev` you only get a stub and a deprecation warning

> This is a stub types definition for Moment
>   (https://github.com/moment/moment). Moment provides its own type
>   definitions, so you don't need @types/moment installed!

Now, i don't know if it's my editor, project or typescript settings or really a typescript issue, but i can't seem to be able to properly import moment's type definitions.

if i do either `import moment from 'moment';` or `import * as moment from 'moment';` i get this error on my editor (atom with atom-typescript, but i have the same error on Visual Studio Code) `Cannot find module 'moment'.`

Despite this error, when i build my application it works fine (calling moment functions works).

I have tried a lot of solutions i found on the internet (apparently, importing type definitions from moment is a common issue) but none worked. 
Yesterday I managed to make it work by manually creating the directory `moment` inside `node_modules/@types` and put `moment.d.ts` inside it (i had to rename it `index.d.ts` though).

Since i didn't really like this solution, i wanted to at least create a types folder i could put stuff into without having to modify `node_modules` structure. So i created a folder `custom-types` and put the `moment` folder with types definitions there, then added `custom-types` into `tsconfig.json`, i thought this would've worked fine but actually the error reappeared...

Now i'm out of ideas, and i don't really know what else to try.

This is my current `tsconfig.json` (in the last attempt to make things work i have added the `custom-types` folder with different paths, although it's on the same level as the `node_modules` folder and `tsconfig.json` file)

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "module": "system",
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "classic",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types/",
            "./custom-types/",
            "custom-types/",
            "../custom-types/",
            "../../custom-types/",
            "../../../custom-types/"
        ],
        "types": [
            "angular-ui-router",
            "angular",
            "angular-mocks",
            "jquery",
            "jasmine",
            "moment",
            "es6-shim"
        ]
    },
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "filesGlob": [
        "custom-types/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx",
        "!jspm_packages/**",
        "!node_modules/**"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been using `moment` in TypeScript (IntelliJ) with no extra work to install typings for it.

Here's the relevant configuration:

- Inside `tsconfig.json`:

  - **`"moduleResolution": "Node"`**
  - No `"types"` section at all
- `./package.json` has no `@types/moment`
- Inside `./node_modules/moment/`:

  - `./moment.d.ts` exists
  - `./package.json` has `"typings": "./moment.d.ts"`
  - `./package.json` is `"version": "2.14.1"`

When I switch back to `"moduleResolution": "Classic"`, TypeScript says `cannot find module 'moment'`. So that is probably the culprit.

Comment: Great to hear! Finding the right settings for `tsconfig.json` can feel like solving a Rubik's Cube sometimes.

Comment: Thanks! The `"moduleResolution": "node"` did part of the trick, but In my case I also had to set `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`.

Comment: Turned out that setting `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to true and adding 
`import moment from 'moment';` broke some of my other requirejs code.
Using `import moment = require('moment');` instead made it work just as well (still needs `"moduleResolution": "Node"`).

Comment: @Worthy7 Cheers

Comment: Thanks Robert. My configuration was the same except: 1) I do have a `types` section  (whose values are `['core-js', 'hammerjs']`), 2) I have `./node_modules/moment/package.json` version `2.22.1` . Also I didn't know the [correct import syntax](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/issues/606#issuecomment-232811042), but `import * as moment from 'moment'` worked for me.